# How to addEventListener to table row and extract data attribure

Tags: addeventlistener, custom-data-attribute

I have a table with data attribute of data-id for each row

```html
<tr class="tableRow" data-id="{{this.id}}">
      <td>{{this.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{this.email}}</td>
 </tr>
```

I'd like to add an EventListener to each row and then extract the id when a row is click.

Here is what I'm trying but is not working:

```js
const rowClick = document.querySelectorAll(".tableRow");

rowClick.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("row was clicked");

  const id = rowClick.getAttribute("data-id");
  console.log(id);

});
```

Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Data Tables plugin to create table. https://datatables.net/ it has inbuilt functions to click row and do something.

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm looking for